# push_back in LinkedList in rust using raw pointers

Tags: rust, singly-linked-list

I wanted to write push_back function for my LinkedList without using recursion and using raw pointers(just to understand and play with unsafe blocks)

My Code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<*mut Node<T>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<*mut Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Display + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    pub(crate) fn push(&mut self, arg: T) {
        let node = &mut Node {
            val: arg,
            next: None,
        } as *mut Node<T>;
        println!("address of node: {:p}", node);
        unsafe {
            println!("val of node: {:?}", (*node).val);
        }
        if self.head.is_none() {
            self.head = Some(node);
            println!("head set");
            return;
        }
        let mut curr = self.head.unwrap();
        unsafe {
            while let Some(node) = (*curr).next {
                curr = node;
            }
            (*curr).next = Some(node);
        }
    }

    fn print(&self)
    where
        T: std::fmt::Display,
    {
        println!("Printing...");

        let mut curr = self.head;

        while let Some(node) = curr {
            unsafe {
                println!("val: {}", (*node).val);
                curr = (*node).next;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = LinkedList::<i32> { head: None };

    l.push(20);
    l.push(30);
    l.push(20);
    l.push(3);
    l.print();
}
```

Output:

```
address of node: 0xa22e6ffaa0
val of node: 20
head set
address of node: 0xa22e6ffaa0
val of node: 30
address of node: 0xa22e6ffaa0
val of node: 20
address of node: 0xa22e6ffaa0
val of node: 3
Printing...
val: 779090824
```

What is wrong with the code?

1. Why every node created in push function is having same address ?
2. When Im trying even print statements are influencing the final result (What !)?

   I removed line `println!("Printing...");` and the last line of the output was `val: 3`

   May be hard luck cause I did run the same adding and removing the line for around 10 times, if its added output was garbage value , by commenting it, output was fine (i.e., last pushed value, in this case 3)
3. Hope my logic is correct

   Any suggestion other than writing it in recursive way is appreciated.

Initially I did the same in cpp and tried doing the same in rust.
CPP code:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node *nxt;
};
struct LinkedList
{
    struct Node *head;
};
void push(LinkedList *l, int v)
{
    struct Node *link = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    link->val = v;
    link->nxt = nullptr;
    if (l->head == nullptr)
    {
        l->head = link;
        return;
    }
    auto curr = l->head;
    while (curr->nxt != nullptr)
    {
        curr = curr->nxt;
    }

    curr->nxt = link;
}
void print(LinkedList *l)
{
    auto curr = l->head;
    // cout << curr << endl;
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        cout << curr->val << endl;
        curr = curr->nxt;
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct LinkedList *ll = (struct LinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
    ll->head = nullptr;
    push(ll, 2);
    push(ll, 3);
    push(ll, 4);
    print(ll);
    cout << "end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
end
```

I was able to do do it in cpp pointers (hope its correct way) or I was lucky, but Im unable to do the same in rust.

I want to do it with pointers, everywhere I find it with using Box smart pointer, I wanna try with raw pointers only.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but your code shows that you do not understand basic memory management (where do you think the node created with `&mut Node { … } as *mut Node<T>` lives?). Moreover, linked lists are a text-book exercise in some other languages, but they are particularly tricky in Rust (which is fine, because linked list are completely useless with modern CPUs). There are better ways to practice low level memory management in Rust.

Comment: I Completely lost touch with the pointers, Initially I wrote the same function in cpp(it worked), thought to convert it to rust to see how it goes. I didnt get what ur saying bro. Sorry, but Im very new to rust's pointers, didnt think about the livetime of pointers, Can u explain briefly, what happens to the pointers

Comment: This would be broken the exact same way in C++. You're taking the address of a temporary. This is UB. UBs may _look like_ they work sometimes, but doing so is broken, be it in Rust or C++.

Comment: but it worked it c++

Comment: I did edit the question and pasted the cpp code , please tell me, where I am wrong

Comment: Your C++ code uses `malloc` to create long-lived allocations on the heap, which is safe. Your Rust code, on the other hand, creates temporary nodes on the stack with `Node { ... }` and takes their addresses, but those temporaries are dropped at the end of the `let` statement.

Comment: I want to second @mcarton's first comment. It is very tempting coming from C++ to try to sprinkle some `unsafe` here and there when the Rust compiler won't let you do something. I did the same thing when I started with Rust because I figured I knew what I was doing. I was wrong. I **strongly** recommend you stay away from `unsafe` until you are much further along. Using it to dodge the borrow checker is almost always a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: For context, I've been doing C++ for twenty years and Rust for two, and I still don't feel confident enough to use `unsafe` with references and pointers. Using it correctly requires incredibly intricate knowledge of how undefined behavior works in Rust. I'm not there yet -- and truth be told I don't know if I ever will be.

Comment: Yeah I know , this is my first ever try of using unsafe blocks , thankfully I didnt get it right in my first go. But I really wonder , Can I create long lived pointers in rust, like rusts equivalent of using malloc and creating a pointer in cpp?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. Start with [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.htm).

Comment: We shouldn't do this here. If you want to keep chatting come to the [Rust chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust).

Comment: I posted my query [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240509/discussion-between-sherlock-sampath-and-john-kugelman)?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Learning Rust With Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Answer (score -1):

Actually the variable node which is created inside function block so after the function gets executed the pointer which u pointed becomes an dangling pointer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).